# What is the best way of randomly re-arranging a list of items in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, random

I have a list of objects and I want to reorder them randomly on each request.  What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: This should really be part of the standard .net class library...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about some kind of [Knuth-Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle) ?

```
for (int i = cards.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    int n = rand.Next(i + 1);
    Swap(ref cards[i], ref cards[n]);
}
```

Code taken from [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001015.html). This is also a recommended reading on how people often do this wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Check out this cool Linq way of doing it:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Populate a list:

```
    List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();

    list.Add(new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Davolio Nancy" });
    list.Add(new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Fuller Andrew" });
    list.Add(new Employee { Id = 3, Name = "Leverling Janet" });
    list.Add(new Employee { Id = 4, Name = "Peacock Margaret" });
    list.Add(new Employee { Id = 5, Name = "Buchanan Steven" });
    list.Add(new Employee { Id = 6, Name = "Suyama Michael" });
    list.Add(new Employee { Id = 7, Name = "King Robert" });
    list.Add(new Employee { Id = 8, Name = "Callahan Laura" });
    list.Add(new Employee { Id = 9, Name = "Dodsworth Anne" });
```

Then sort:

```
    list = list.OrderBy(emp => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
```

[Credit](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/random_sort_a_list_using_linq.aspx)

Comment: Not exactly fast, but friggen awesome.

Comment: Who cares about performance when you can whip out your big LINQ stick and show others you're better than them? :-P

Comment: Just remember that GUID's are **NOT** to be treated as random numbers for crypto purposes.  They'll work for this kind of thing, but they're not interchangeable.

Comment: Goddamn right!  Until we HAVE a requirement for doing it fast, that is.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx use a class similar to the example code to generate a cryptographically random number rather than using NewGuid().  No word on performance on this, tho.

Comment: Linq rules.  I think would take a random number over a GUID though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) algorithm which runs in linear-time.

Comment: Produces incorrect results - see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001015.html

Answer (score 2):

Let me direct you to one **WRONG** way of doing it, and a way I confess I used before, and never saw the error of it until this blog post:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001015.html

Answer (score 1):

My favorite solution to shuffling stuff is use an N*log N sort and pass it a sort predicate that returns a random result. It has the nice feature that is can be done with a minimum of new code using building blocks that most languages have handy in even the most striped versions.

Comment: On the other hand a shuffle is only O(n) and is only about 5 lines of code, as shown in other answers. (And can be done just once with generics very easily.)

Comment: 5 lines to 1 line is either not much (only 4 lines) or a lot (80%). Also it's simpler to remember.

Comment: And the other advantage is that the sort might leverage something to get good perf on the swaps so for small n it might be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new List and filling it with items that are randomly selected and removed from the original List.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code [here](http://codegator.com/mcook/archive/2007/04/10/random-sorting-in-c.aspx)

It uses the IComparer.Compare

It will be a good practice if you do the function using [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172194.aspx)